# Draw on background rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[framed, background rectangle/.style={draw=black!15,fill=black!5,rounded corners=1ex}]
        \node (a) at (1,1) {a};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It produces:

[image: picture1]

Now I want to have an ellipse on the top darker line like:

[image: picture2]

My problem is that this ellipse should be predefined by some definition which gets at `#1` some text to be drawn inside the ellipse. Finally I want to save the "style" (maybe its an option I couldn't get it by long research) as `mybackground`. So my aim is to write:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[mybackground=#1]
        \node (a) at (1,1) {a};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To get the same result but now it should get `#1` and write it in the ellipse.

*Edit:* The answer from Harish Kumar works perfect. For those who wondering what this for:
(The ellipse and the '4' are the point of this question)

[image: result]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some thing like this?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,backgrounds}

\tikzset{
  mybackground/.style={execute at end picture={
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
          \draw[black!15,fill=black!5,rounded corners=1ex] (current bounding box.south west)
                    rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
          \node[draw,fill=olive,ellipse,anchor=west,inner sep=1pt,minimum width=4ex] at (current bounding box.north
                   west){#1};
        \end{scope}
    }},
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[mybackground={here}]
        \node[minimum width=1in,minimum height=1in] (a) at (1,1) {abcd};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have no idea of your use case. If you provide details, you may get more specific answers that may include `tcolorbox`.

Comment: Thank you very much Harish, that is on the first view exactly(!) what I was looking for I'll test it. Btw: I also tried `on background layer` but it has thrown an error. It seems `execute at end picture` is the point. I'll edit some details for what it is useful.

Comment: That works perfect. Thank you very much! If you know a better title please let me know.

Comment: @TimS. For this specific use, this approach is better. `tcolorbox` is like a swiss army knife.

Comment: I know `tcolorbox` but it's like most of the other packages: They don't have a focus on beautiful design. With my code together with your solution it's a short code and with an excellent result IMO.

Answer (score 6):

In case someone is interested next code shows a solution with `tcolorbox`. This package was mentioned in Harish's answer comments and it's devoted to produce framed and colorful boxes.

The code shows two different kind of boxes `\mybox` and `\mytikzbox` which share a common style called `mystyle`. `\mybox` and `\mytikzbox` are declared with `\newtcbox` command in order to adjust their width to their contents. `\newtcolorbox` command declares environments with fixed width (`\linewidth` by default).

While `\mybox` is valid for any kind of contents, `\mytikzbox` is only valid for `tikzpictures` (which seems to be OP intention). In this case, `\mytikzbox` contents is automatically surrounded by the pair `\begin{tikzpicture}` - `\end{tikzpicture}` which needs to be explicitly included in `\mybox`.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{mystyle/.style={
    enhanced, 
    coltitle = black, 
    colframe = black!15,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2, xshift=2ex},
    boxed title style={enhanced, 
        frame code={\draw[black!15, line width=.5mm, fill=white, 
            rounded corners=1.75ex] 
            (frame.south west) rectangle (frame.north east);}, 
        interior empty}
    }}

\newtcbox{\mybox}[2][]{mystyle, #1, title=#2}

\newtcbox{\mytikzbox}[2][]{mystyle, tikz upper, #1, title=#2}

\begin{document}

\mybox{1}{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[circle, red, fill=red!30] (a) {A};
        \node[circle, blue, fill=blue!30] (b) at (2,2) {B};
        \draw[thick,green] (a)--(b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\mytikzbox{2}{
        \node[circle, red, fill=blue!30] (a) {A};
        \node[circle, blue, fill=red!30] (b) at (2,2) {B};
        \draw[thick,purple] (a)--(b);
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First of all: a nice solution too. You also set the title as an argument. But here we do not get the main (wished) result setting a tikz option. That was exactly the reason why I decided to use plain tikz. For instance: In the solution by Harish Kumar you can draw the same picture with option and without and get two complete different results. So if I want my picture to have the gray background with title i just set the option and if not I get the standard result.

Comment: @TimS. With this solution if you leave title empty (`\mybox{}{...}` or `\mytikzbox{}{...}`) you also get a complete different result: a framed box with certain background color and without title. You can change background or frame color with first optional parameter: `\mybox[colframe=red]{}{...}`.

Comment: By using `\mytikzbox[colframe=white]{}{...}` I still get a light gray background. But it's good to see that it's also possible to get beautiful results using `tcolorbox`.